# In python,why use function to get class member?

Tags: python, c++, function, class

Hi, recently I read some codes of others , and found the differences between others and mine is that they often write a function to get class member. Like

```
def GetHeight
    return self.height
```

instead of just using

```
self.height
```

in the program.

I mean, in C++, I know the function of this is to get **private** member.
In python, though everything is set as **public** (in normal cases) ,
Why it has reason to be used in python? Is that just bad code?
Or something else I ignore?
I am kinda new to python, so I will appreciate it if you give some advice.

**EDIT:**
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors) It seems my question has been identified as the duplicate of another one. I checked the answer and found the answer of that is more like general advice instead of pythonic programming.

While the answer below introduces a feature of python -- **property**
That possibly cannot be learned from that question, so it's the reason I think my question is unique.

Comment: It is just convention/good practice I believe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python it is unnecessary to create a getter method (especially if the getter simply returns the attribute value with no checks or modifications). You can implement meaningful get and set methods but they should actually do something. The preferred approach is to use property decorators as described here: [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work)

```
class Building(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._height = 100

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._height

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        if 0 < value < 1000:
            self._height = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Attribute: height must be between 0 and 1000.')
```

Then the property methods are used when reading from or assigning to the attribute:

```
b = Building()

print(b.height)
100

b.height = 90
print(b.height)
90

b.height = 2000
print(b.height)
90
```

By convention, reserved attributes are preceded by a single underscore and private attributes by a double underscore. However, this is more to alert users of the class that the attributes should be handled with care and nothing prevents them from accessing the attributes.

Comment: Upvoted, but the setter should raise a `ValueError`, not just silently swallow the error.

Answer (score 1):

it's a matter of preference.  python lets the programmer be OO or imperative as suits.  the whole notion of accessors and mutators is old fashioned for some and beloved by others.